# Dynamically add the treelist and assign datatable as datasource in devexpress

Tags: devexpress-windows-ui

I have datatable of columns parent_id, child_id, and another some columns.
I want to create the treelist at run time and assign the above datatable as datasource. 
Upto this step it works good. But it never shows the columns in tree list.
and that treelist control attached to xtratab control, and it showing nothing.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us some of your code

Comment: TreeList targetTree = new TreeList();   targetTree.DataSource = GetDataSource();//method which returns datatable

Comment: Hi marko, Is this code is satisfactory to you?